# Work with this implicitely defined function

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I want to check whether the following transformation is correct:

$$ \sum_{s=1}^\infty (1-x)^s \exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^s}{s!} = \exp(-\lambda)\sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{X^s}{s!}\\
= \exp(-\lambda)\exp(X) = \exp(1-x)
$$

Where the first line comes from the Taylor expansion. I'm curious whether that can be applied here, and is the normal way to proceed - and whether there are "but care, this only holds for certain values of $x$" caution tales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly bring the constant $e^{-\lambda}$ outside of the sum. The remaining sum is $e^{\lambda(1-x)}-1$. The "$-1$" appears here because the sum as written starts at index $s=1$ rather than $s=0$, so the constant term needs to be accounted for.

Assuming that was not a typo, the result would be $e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda}$.

**Addendum:** Also, this is valid for all values of $x$ since this particular sum has an infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: I'm not following: Are you saying the first equality is incorrect, or the second one? It indeed is not a typo, the sum starts at one.

Comment: I believe the last equality is incorrect. I presume that "$X$" is "$\lambda(1-x)$"?

Comment: To be explicit, this is the correct way to simplify the product: $$e^{-\lambda}[\underbrace{e^{\lambda(1-x)}-1}_{\textrm{the sum}}]=e^{-\lambda+\lambda-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda} = e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda}$$

Comment: Ah, so already the second equality is incorrect. I see. Thanks.